# Can I prevent camel from decoding query params.?

Tags: spring, rest, apache-camel

Camel decodes the URL Params. Is there a way I get the URL I sent in. 
I have below scenario(Spring XML & Camel):

```
<route id="getDepResources">
        <from uri="restlet:/dep/{depId}/resources?restletMethods=GET"/>
<bean ref="deptUtility" method="process" />
</route>

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    Message message = exchange.getIn();
    String body = message.getBody(String.class);
    String uri = message.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, String.class);
......
}

curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/app1/dep/1/resources?resourceDesc=R%26B'  --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

So for resourceDesc=R%26B (R & B) I need to get it as R%26B while the URI on line 3 I get is `http://localhost:8080/app1/dep/1/resources?resourceDesc=R&B`  while I thought it should be `http://localhost:8080/app1/dep/1/resources?resourceDesc=R%26B` . Is there a configuration I can do for same or any other way? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to camel directly, it's related to the specification of an URI : an URI should be decoded by a UA.

You should quote the percent character if you want to get it as is. The quote for `%` is `%25`

Comment: Sorry but I am appending & as %26 i:e resourceDesc=R%26B (R&B is the actual text).  I wish to get it as %26 rather than &.(Maintain the URL as it is)

Comment: message.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, String.class) does the same.

Comment: Because it's tot related to camel: The URI is decoded before. If you want your application to get R%26B, you must encode the %, `R%2526B`.